# Rails' Paperclip gem POSTing instead of PUTting when uploading .zip file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zip, paperclip

I've got a form (Rails 3.2.8, Paperclip 3.1.4) with two Paperclip attachments for a model with two has_attached_files. One is meant to be an image, the other a generic file, usually a .zip file.

Everything works fine so long as I don't try to upload a .zip file. Uploading a .zip file of any size (original was 80 MB but tried 3 MB to see if it was a size issue) causes the form to POST instead of PUT and Rails throws a routing error.

The form method is POST but has the Rails' hidden _method value set to 'put', which works fine and does cause a PUT when I'm not trying to upload .zip files.

The form does have the enctype 'multipart' bit set correctly.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: try with a couple of different file types, and see if that makes a difference. Also,if it's supposed to be a PUT call, why not just explicitly define that with :method => "PUT"?

Comment: code would be nice to see. This answer may help others if you solved it.

Comment: does that happens ONLY for .zip files? have you tried another file type? also, what's your post limit on the server? maybe you are exceeding it with both the image and the zip, try two small files (like... a 100k image and a 100k zip)

Comment: @Solomon I guess it's the case, Chris was referring to the html output.

Comment: I agree with pjammer, please add some code to make your problem solvable. Edit your SO question if needed to improve it.

Comment: Track down code using `pry`.

Comment: pasting a log of a request might be helpful too

Comment: Share your form_for code here.

Answer (score 1):

The file sounds large. Double check that the actual params are making it into the request. I get this on local as well depending on the size of the files.

The effect I've seen is that rails would basically get no params. Since a PUT is actually a post with a hidden element, rails would see only the POST since params are dropped.

I am actually not sure what is causing this. I think it may be the local webserver, so you may need to configure nginx or something. This never happens to me on heroku or anything, but always on local if the file is big enough.

Also note, webrick has a really really small size of the request payload limitation. So don't use that. Use "thin" as it is a really easy replacement.